# Hot to build x86 and ARM apks without Crosswalk?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I decided to remove Crosswalk from my Cordova project. The size added to the apk is ridiculous and really increased my "Uninstall Rate".

But without Crosswalk cordova won't generate two apks ARM and x86. How to set it manually in Cordova?

**Is the single apk generated by Cordova already hybrid architecture?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the single apk generated by Cordova is already hybrid architecture and will run on both platform.

If you want to build multi platform apk as before, you can do so in number of ways described [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#project-configuration) :

The easiest way is to use a command line flag when running or building cordova app:

```
$ cordova build android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvBuildMultipleApks=true
```